# Why is MacOS M2 pro still in my iCloud after factory reset?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, restart

Mac book pro M2 (13") Monterey: I followed the steps described by the [official guide "Erase your Mac and reset it to factory settings"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212749)

> 1. From the Apple menu  in the corner of your screen, choose System Preferences.
> 2. From the System Preferences menu in the menu bar, choose Erase All Content and Settings.
>
> After choosing Erase All Content and Settings, follow these steps to continue:
>
> 1. An erase assistant asks you to sign in with your administrator credentials. Enter the password that you use to log in to your Mac, then click OK.
> 2. If you're asked to back up your Mac before resetting it, you can open Time Machine and back up to an external storage device. Or click Continue to proceed without making a new backup.
> 3. Click Continue to allow your settings, media, data, and the other listed items to be removed.
>    [image]
> 4. If you're asked to sign out of Apple ID, enter your Apple ID password and click Continue.
> 5. Click Erase All Content & Settings to confirm that you want to proceed
>    [image]

## Successful factory reset while device still visible in iCloud

Following this the M2 Pro restarted and lead me to the expected screen:

[image]

I did NOT use the setup assistant - as I wanted to leave the device in an out of box state.

However: logging into my iCloud account the device was still under "My Devices"

[image]

At first I thought it might be a syncing issue: so I checked in a few hours. The device still shows up in my account. So I waited 24 hrs. The device is still registered.

What did I miss?

Comment: The iCloud 'ownership' is not stored on the device, but in iCloud. If you want to remove it from your list of devices, then that's a different and separate process.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that I could still locate it even if I sold it via "Find my"?

Comment: Yes: that's why it's important to remove it from your devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The erase removes it from Find My quite reliably in my tests, but I expect there are situations where even that might fail. I don't think you missed anything and just need to remove it from the online site to finish the cleanup you desire.

Have you tried locating it in Find My after this event?

When you remove it from the iCloud online settings, it should let you know that it's gone unless the device is still signed in which would then renew the connection on Apple's servers between that serial and your storage / account.

My hunch is you can no longer track that Mac and everything worked as expected, but you would need to open a case with Apple support if needed and they would go through the steps and perhaps have you grant them support access via a PIN exchange to inspect your data with your permission on their servers if you can't come to a good answer here or with their initial help.